# SQL Substring problem - removing certain characters and re-structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to get this problem done, trying to get transform this string

```
"1. Create Event Flyer,3. Create Press Release,5. Promote - Social Media & Website"
```

Into something like

```
Create Event Flyer / Create Press Release / Promote - Social Media & Website
```

I have been trying to use left and replace but it still can't get it right :( much appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can highlight the query which you are using, and the output you are getting

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(RIGHT(value,(LEN(value)-CHARINDEX(' ',value))) ,' / ')
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1. Create Event Flyer,3. Create Press Release,5. Promote - Social Media & Website',',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following
The idea is

- first, use STRING_SPLIT to split string by ','
- second, use STUFF to replace first two characters ( 1, 2. etc)
- last, use FOR XML to concat them again

> ```
> DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)
> SET @str ='1. Create Event Flyer,3. Create Press Release,5. Promote - Social Media & Website'
> SELECT STUFF((
>   SELECT  ' / ' + STUFF(value,1,2,'')  
>   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ',') 
>   FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,3,'')
> ```

SQL Fiddle Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/67411

Comment: You were missing a parenthesis. :D

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange :)

Comment: @EricZ Consider that: 1.`STRING_SPLIT()` doesn't guarantee the order of the substrings, and 2. You may use `REPLACE()` to change `,` with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use recursive CTE:

```
declare @t varchar(500) = '1. Create Event Flyer,3. Create Press Release,5. Promote - Social Media & Website'

;With cte
as
(
    select @t as string,0  as n
    union all
    select
        cast(replace(string,concat(',', n, '. '), iif(n = 1, '', ' / ')) as varchar(500)),n+1
    from cte
    where n<9
)
select top 1 string from cte
order by n desc
```